# Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

Tags: parsing, module, utf-8, charset

./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?ngGlobalStyle:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'
(1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> @charset "utf-8";/*!
> |  * Bootstrap  v5.2.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
> |  * Copyright 2011-2022 The Bootstrap Authors

I don't have webpack.  Angular CLI manages the build configuration internally. The error message  suggests that there is a problem with parsing the bootstrap.min.css file, specifically due to the presence of the @ character at the beginning. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.